# Find points of Pinch Gesture

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I am familiar with UIGestures but this specific need made me hit the wall.

Question: How to find the starting two points and ending two points of a UIPinchGesture?

I have to get all those four points and have to make some calculations at the server side.

Someone ever tried it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touchPositionOne = [[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
UITouch *touchPositionTwo = [[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
CGPoint fps = [touchPositionOne locationInView:self.imageView];
CGPoint sps = [touchPositionTwo locationInView:self.imageView];

NSLog(@"%@ %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(fps), NSStringFromCGPoint(sps));
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touchPositionOne = [[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
UITouch *touchPositionTwo = [[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
CGPoint fps = [touchPositionOne locationInView:self.imageView];
CGPoint sps = [touchPositionTwo locationInView:self.imageView];

NSLog(@"%@ %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(fps), NSStringFromCGPoint(sps));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

use

```
- (CGPoint)locationOfTouch:(NSUInteger)touchIndex inView:(UIView *)view
```

like

```
[gesture locationOfTouch:0 inView:youView]; //first
[gesture locationOfTouch:1 inView:youView]; //second
```

Comment: Sorry to say. Until I run this code in device everything was fine and i was quiet happy. But it device it have some sigAbrts. For UIPinchGesture UITouch[2] is the usual value and it is readOnly(ie no setter for it). But when I access the index at 1, XCode says: "Out of bounds". :(

Comment: you should first check [gesture numberOfTouches] ,  but PinchGesture must have 2 points

Comment: I was trying it this way and it works, but when I take my fingers of the screen, my app crashes at the line with `locationOfTouch:inView:` with SIGABRT, and no message. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint point1 = [gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:piece];
CGPoint point2 = [gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:piece];
CGPoint center = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece];
```

Comment: thanks. But I had already figured out a solution long back. Please find above answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in XCode 12 you can use location(ofTouch:, in:) to identify location of points:

```
print(sender.location(ofTouch: 0, in: view))
print(sender.location(ofTouch: 1, in: view))
```